# Server sent events in pedestal returns empty response

Tags: javascript, clojure, response, server-sent-events, pedestal

I am currently implementing server sent events (SSE) in an web application using Clojure, Pedestal and Jetty.

When I print the message in the backend the channel is open and when I invoke `io.pedestal.http.sse/send-event` it returns true, however in the frontend I get no console.log() prints in Javascript in the browser console. as if there is no data received. I tested the SSE connection in Postman and it is successful but the response is `(empty)`.

Backend:

```
    (def SSE-REGISTRY (atom {}))
     
     (defn get-user-channel [token]    
       (get @SSE-REGISTRY token))
     
     (defn test-print [channel]    
       (println "channel:" channel) ;; channel:#object[clojure.core.async.impl.chan...]   
       (println "channel opened:" (not (chan/closed? channel))) ;; channel opened: true  
       (println "sent-event:" 
       (sse/send-event channel "status"
         (json/write-str {:id 1
                          :workflowId 3
                          :status :GOOD}) ;; sent-event: true
     
     (defn send-sse-msg [name data id]   
       (when-let [sse-channels (vals @SSE-REGISTRY)]
         (doseq [channel sse-channels] 
           (when-not (chan/closed? channel)
             (test-print channel)
             (sse/send-event channel name data id)))))   

(def sse-route ["/rest/sse" :get 
                  (sse/start-event-stream send-sse-msg 60 100) 
                  :route-name :sse])
     
     (defn create-sse-channel []   
        (async/chan (async/sliding-buffer 100)))
```

[image]

Frontend:

```
 const protocol = window.location.protocol;
const host = window.location.port; 
const sseUrl = protocol + '//'+ host + '/rest/sse';
const RUN_BUTTON_STATUS_TIME = 2000;
const sseInitOptionsMap = {
                            headers: {
                                       'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8',
                                       'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
                                       'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' 
                                      },
                            withCredentials: true,
                            https: {rejectUnauthorized: true}
                          };

export const eventSource = new EventSource(sseUrl, sseInitOptionsMap);
eventSource.addEventListener('integrationStatus', sendStatusHandler);
eventSource.addEventListener('stopAction', sendStopActionHandler);

eventSource.onopen = (e) => {
  console.log("SSE connection opened:" + e);
};

eventSource.onerror = (e) => {
  console.log("error:" + e);
  if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
      console.log("connection closed:" + e);
  } else {
    eventSource.close();
    console.log("SSE connection closed:" + e);
  }
};

export function sendStatusHandler(event) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log("data:" + data);
  let id = data.id;
  let workflowId = data.workflowId;
  let status = data.status;
  cljsDisp("set-global-operation-status", id, workflowId, status);
  configurtorActionRunButtonStatus(id, workflowId, status);
  setTimeout(cljsDisp("get-last-run-action-data", id, workflowId, status),
             300);
}

function configurtorActionRunButtonStatus (id, workflowId, status) {
  if (status === "GOOD") {
    showStatus(id, workflowId, true);
  } else if (status === "BAD") {
    showStatus(id, workflowId, true);
    cljsDisp("configurator-error-message-show", id, workflowId, true);
  } else {
    cljsDisp("configurator-action-run-button-status-visible?", id, workflowId, false);
  }
}

export function sendStopWorkflowHandler(event) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log("data:" + data); // prints nothing
  let workflowId = data.workflowId;
  cljsDisp("stop-action-by-sse-msg", workflowId);
}

function showStatus(integrationId, operationId, showStatus) {
  setTimeout(cljsDisp("configurator-action-run-button-status-visible?", 
                      integrationId, operationId, showStatus),
             RUN_BUTTON_STATUS_TIME);
}

export function closeSse() {
  if (eventSource.readyState != eventSource.CLOSED) {
    eventSource.close();
  }
}
```

[image]

It seems I am missing something. Can you help. The problem is that there are not much examples of Clojure with Pedestal implementation of SSE. Most are in JavaScript and other languages.
[This is the implementation of pedestal SSE itself](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/0.6.1/service/src/io/pedestal/http/sse.clj#L60)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small example on [the pedestal docs](http://pedestal.io/pedestal/0.6/guides/sse.html) which you could add as a separate route.

The basic issue with your code is that when your create the intercepor with:

```
(sse/start-event-stream send-sse-msg 60 100)
```

send-sse-msg function should be one that takes 2 args, the channel and the context of the original request.  Context can be deconstructed as with any other interecptor.

A slightly modified version of the docs example that uses context is:

```
(defn sse-stream-ready
  "Starts sending counter events to client."
  [event-ch context]
  (let [count-num (Integer/parseInt
                   (get-in context [:request :query-params :counter] "5"))]
    (loop [counter count-num]
      (async/put!
       event-ch {:name "count"
                 :data (str counter ", T: "
                            (.getId (Thread/currentThread)))})
      (Thread/sleep 2000)
      (if (> counter 1)
        (recur (dec counter))
        (do
          (async/put! event-ch {:name "close" :data "I am done!"})
          (async/close! event-ch))))))
```

Your code looks more like you would save the event-  channel into your registry (keyed by some context element?) and have another async function sending messages to all channels (chat like is what I infer there).

Comment: Actually the registry stores the `[session-token channel]` pair for every user which is logged in. I use it to take the channel for the specific user to live update it about a status changes in the application. The channel is only one for a given user because before the SSE implemenatation websockets worked and they consumed too much resources.

Comment: ok but I don't think that changes the root cause which is that the function you are passing to sse/send-event is wrong.  It should take the (new) event-channel and the context